# Rails 4: how to add dynamic global variables from config controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im looking to add an application-level global banner, populated by input data from our CMS.  We add homepage settings in our config controller, but i want that data to be accessible from every page.  It's only working from our home page and every other page gives a Nil:NilClass error.  I'm a python developer and this concept confuses me in rails - In python you could just 'from app.models import model' and that would make it accessible - how would I do this in rails?  Sorry if this is hard to understand, I'm not very good at ruby on rails.

Im looking to access 'ticker_copy' from the config controller

config controller:

```
def edit
    @path = admin_edit_config_path
  end

  def update
    @path = admin_edit_config_path
    if @config.update(config_params)
      redirect_to admin_edit_config_path, notice: 'Settings successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit, notice: 'Settings could not be updated.'
    end
  end

  private
    def set_config
      @config = Config.first
      authorize @config
    end

    def set_alternate_message_options
      @alternate_message_options = Config::ALTERNATE_MESSAGES.map{|am| [ am, am ]}
    end
    def set_first_alternate_message_options
      @first_alternate_message_options = Config::FIRST_ALTERNATE_MESSAGES.map{|am| [ am, am ]}
    end

    def config_params
      params.require(:config).permit(
        :show_default_hours,
        :custom_hours,
        :show_ticker,
        :ticker_copy,
        :ticker_link,
        :ticker_link_copy,
        :show_default_message,
        :first_alternate_message,
        :alternate_message,
        :show_default_link,
        :left_custom_link_title,
        :left_custom_link_url,
        :custom_link_title,
        :custom_link_url,
        :tour_hours,
        :home_page_video,
        :remove_home_page_video
      )
    end
```

application controller: I'm trying to do something like this

```
def set_ticker
    @ticker_copy = config.find(params[:ticker_copy])
end
```

models:

```
field :ticker_copy, type: String
```

HTML partial

```
<h1 id="ticker">
  <%= @config.ticker_copy %>
</h1>
```

Im using Rails 4.2.6

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're asking here. Could you clarify what line is giving you a nil error message?

Comment: How are `set_ticker` and `set_config` being run? You have a `before_action` for each? Maybe your issue is they're being run in the wrong order. You could verify that.

Answer (score 0):

Your `set_ticker` method looks incorrect. `Config.find` looks up the record by the primary key. I think what you're trying to do is

```
def set_ticker
    @ticker_copy = Config.find_by(ticker_copy: params[:ticker_copy])
end
```